# Removing NULLs after using a case statement and returning multiple results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use some CASE statements to extract corresponding information from an activity log. The gist of the activity log is the working ID will have multiple activities and dates, here is a simplify i.e.:

```html
+-----+--------------------------+-------------+
| ID  |         activity         |    date     |
+-----+--------------------------+-------------+
| 123 | assigned                 | 2016-01-05  |
| 123 | escalated                | 2016-01-06  |
| 123 | returned from escalation | 2016-01-07  |
| 123 | escalated                | 2016-01-08  |
| 123 | returned from escalation | 2016-01-09  |
| 123 | completed                | 2016-02-06  |
+-----+--------------------------+-------------+
```

I used multiple CASE statements to turn the results into something like this:

```html
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
| ID  |  assigned  | escalated  |  returned  |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
| 123 | 2016-01-05 | NULL       | NULL       |
| 123 | NULL       | 2016-01-06 | NULL       |
| 123 | NULL       | NULL       | 2016-01-07 |
| 123 | NULL       | 2016-01-08 | NULL       |
| 123 | NULL       | NULL       | 2016-01-09 |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
```

How can I get rid of the NULLs and turn it into something roughly like:

```html
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
| ID  |  assigned  | escalated  |  returned  |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
| 123 | 2016-01-05 | 2016-01-06 | 2016-01-07 |
| 123 | NULL       | 2016-01-08 | 2016-01-09 |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+
```

The closest I have gotten is by doing what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730095/eliminating-nulls-when-using-case-in-sql-server-select-statement) person has suggested. Unfortunately using MAX or MIN and grouping by ID only give me one unique result. I am currently trying to put the the cases in a CTE, but not sure where to go from there.

Comment: *Roughly like this* doesn't help us answer the question. What exactly do you need it to look like? How do you logically get from the 2nd output to the 3rd?

Comment: is `completed` activity relevant here?

Comment: It needs to look like the table I demonstrated, but the NULL field under assigned could stay as NULL or capture the first assigned (2016-01-05) OR if there is a second assigned, it would capture that. I don't know how to get from the 2nd to get the 3rd output. And completed activity has no relevance, but just to demonstrate an example of the activity log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using conditional aggregation *with `row_number()`*:

```
select t.id,
       max(case when activity = 'assigned' then date end) as assigned,
       max(case when activity = 'escalated' then date end) as escalated,
       max(case when activity = 'returned from escalation ' then date end) as returned
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, activity order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id, seqnum;
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you! Can you explain what is happening with the following statement: `select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, activity order by date) as seqnum
      from t`

What exactly is row_number over and partition doing in conjunction?